# How can I make Samsung Note 10.1 dual boot with Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-for-android

I have a Samsung Note 10.1 with Android 4.1.2 and I want to ask if it is possible to make it dual boot with Ubuntu. (and how of course)

Answer (score 2):

There are three things when it comes to ubuntu & mobile phone.

**Ubuntu as native installation with true dual boot**

There are some work regarding a true dual boot in galaxy note 10.1.
You can get more details at this XDA thread- 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=39622960

Guide mentioned in the thread - http://thermatk.github.com/opensgn-easy/

**Install ubuntu as emulator**

This method runs ubuntu as using a very well known method known as `chroot`.

Here you install `Ubuntu desktop` to your phone. It is just like running ubuntu as a virtual machine under android.

So you can call it dual boot, since you will be using `ubuntu desktop`, which is not optimized for mobile device. **So you may face problem.**

You can start, http://sourceforge.net/p/linuxonandroid/wiki/Home/

**[Ubuntu for android](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/android)**

from wiki

Ubuntu for Android is an upcoming free and open source variant of Ubuntu designed to run on Android phones.

Both Ubuntu and Android run at the same time on the device, without emulation or virtualization, and without the need to reboot. This is possible because both Ubuntu and Android share the same kernel (Linux).

There is no emulation or virtualization. When phone is on, android will be shown. when docked a monitor, phone will turn off and in monitor Ubuntu will load.

If this is the thing you want, sorry it isn't available as of now. It is supposed to come as pre loaded.

**[Ubuntu for Phone](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/phone)**

This is interesting.

Ubuntu for Phone is a mobile operating system. This operating system can use lower level android code. So if your phone as CM10 base, you can use it.

But **Dual Booting : Not possible**

Here are the [list](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/) of devices on which different devs are working to port it. Your device is on that list too.

Here is status of your device - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices/n8000

Here is install instruction : http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2168999